# send browser string in rails functional tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, functional-testing

The application should set the locale based on browser settings, but I don't realize how to test it. I don't know what code sample could I provide to explain, but the test is something like this:

```
def test_locale_settings
    get :index, {}, {:user_id => 1} # send browser settings to english
    assert_select '.nav .welcome', :text => 'Welcome'
    get :index, {}, {:user_id => 1} # send browser settings to spanish
    assert_select '.nav .welcome', :text => 'Bienvenido'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this works, but give it a try:

```
def test_locale_settings
    @request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"] = "en"
    get :index, {}, {:user_id => 1} # send browser settings to english
    assert_select '.nav .welcome', :text => 'Welcome'

    @request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"] = "es"
    get :index, {}, {:user_id => 1} # send browser settings to spanish
    assert_select '.nav .welcome', :text => 'Bienvenido'
end
```

Of course your application will need to know how to parse the format of the HTTP Accept Language header.

Comment: yeah, I had to put two blocks in different methods because it were not reflecting the sencond =/ .. but thats the trick. Thank you.